# Android, calling class method AFTER receiving message from service

Tags: android, service, bundle, handler, message

Well, I have a service, I have an Activity. They communicate via messages (It must communicate with messages so don't tell me about Intents or other things, please).

I receive a Bundle from the Service, all ok.

Now with the Bundle i've received I want to do something. I want to call a method from "SomeClass", but I can't, because I'm inside of "IncomingHandler" class.

What's the best way to call SomeClass from inside IncomingHandler?

Thanks in advance

```
class SomeClass implements ServiceConnection {
    class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                    case MyService.MS_GET_SOMETHING:
                         Bundle received=msg.getData();
                         ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want the activity to be calling methods on the service, its time to learn about AIDL, which allows an Activity to make function calls on a bound service via an RPC mechanism.  [Documentation found here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)

Comment: No, no, I need to call a method from the activity. I need to call it from inside the handlemessage. When I recieve a message, I need to do something with the information I recieved, right? And the method is in the activity class :( Thanks, anyway!

Comment: Thanks but I took another approach, I did a field private SomeClass father=this; and then, from inside the class: father.somemethod(); That worked :D

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the feature (Service calls method in activity) like this:

Service sends a broadcast-message.

Activity has a local nested broadcastreceiver that can call a method in the parent activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = null;

    class _RemoteTimeTrackerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
                            // call method in activity
            reloadGui();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (myReceiver == null)
        {
            myReceiver = new _RemoteTimeTrackerReceiver();
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Global.REFRESH_GUI);
            registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
        }

        reloadGui();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {

        if (myReceiver != null)
        {
            unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
            myReceiver = null;
        }

        super.onPause();

    }

            void reloadGui() {}
```